# How to launch android application from my html5 mobile web application

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to android and mobile Dev

I have created mobile application in html5 and we have an android application ready for scanning purpose developed in android and I need to open this android application from html5 application which is running on a browser. I am not sure how to call, I seen some applications, in which the mobile device will ask for the application to open(for example camera and media players in facebook mobile application).  Please let me know is there any mechanism that user can click on button from my html mobile app and mobile will open my android application which is installed on my mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this an `<intent-filter>` with a `<data>` element.

For example, to handle all links to yourdomain.com, you'd put this inside your `<activity>` in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="yourdomain.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

or

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now in Html page give anchr tag like

```
<a href="my.special.scheme">
```

Actually magic reside in your manifest file
You need to declare activity as a browsable.

Sample Code.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="mywebsite.com"
                    android:path="/somepath/openNativeApp"
                    android:scheme="nativescheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And your Anchor tag will look like

```
 <a href="nativescheme://mywebsite.com/somepath/openNativeApp">
```

Comment: Hi Hardik Trivedi, Can you share any sample application source code. It will help me a lot.

Comment: Edited the answer. Provided the sample code from one of my app.

Comment: Hi Hardik Trivedi, it is resolved Thanks for your help. I can able to call andriod application from web application. I need some more help. if andriod application is not available in mobile . it is showing error message "Page Not Found .......", but we dont show that message to customer. we have guide customer to connect google app store if andriod application is not available in mobile. please share is there any way for this.